# Fragments automatically starts reloading in release app android

Tags: java, android

So i was searching for the solution of this problem from last 1 month and today finally i surrender myself to stack overflow. Let me first explain the scenario i am facing in my release app.

The app works great in below Android 10 versions. But in android 10 version in release mode when the app is opened sometimes it start reloading the app in a continuous loop and finally the app goes blank. No crashes so not able to track the actual source.

My app is having a bottom tab with 4 fragments. So when the problem starts, then let's say i click tab 3, its takes me to tab 2 and reload the activity and then tab 2 opens and again activity reloads and it continues until the app hangs.

I have gone through the Logcat and nothing so clear.

But i got few suggestions over the internet search and applied them but still the issue persists.

My applied solutions --

1. setting

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in AndroidManifest.xml as per the suggestion found for Nat64 prefix issue.

2. Setting Fragment Transaction in the below manner --

   ```
                             FragmentTransaction FT = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                               if(fragment == null)
                               {
                                   fragment = new Main_F();

                                   FT.addToBackStack(null);
                                   FT.add(R.id.RL_id, fragment).commit();
                               }
                               else {

                                   if(fragment.isDetached()) {
                                       FT.attach(fragment);
                                   } else {

                                   }
                               }
   ```
3. Commented these 2 lines --

   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

The above solutions are not working, i identified these from the logcat message.
But still the issue appears.
So i have no other option and i came here for some ideas.

I am adding the logcat data also --

```
D/fling_: {"code":"200","msg":[{"response":"success"}]}
D/numTouch: 82
D/fling_: {"code":"200","msg":[{"response":"success"}]}
D/numTouch: 83
D/fling_: {"code":"200","msg":[{"response":"success"}]}
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 85.0.4183.101 (code 418310183)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Loaded native library version number "85.0.4183.101"
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder: Flushed 5 samples from 5 histograms.
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: Dispatching InputEvent took 126ms in main thread! (MotionEvent: event_seq=1863, seq=2398961, action=ACTION_UP)
D/numTouch: 84
E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/com.sp1.fling/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
W/com.sp1.fling: Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.sp1.fling: Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.sp1.fling: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
D/fling_: {"code":"200","msg":[{"response":"success"}]}
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: Long Msg: seq=5273 plan=21:20:04.160  late=0ms wall=2017ms running=16ms h=android.os.Handler c=com.sp1.fling.All_Fragments.Profile_F$2
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: MotionEvent is 1968ms late (event_seq=1999, action=ACTION_DOWN) because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 2017ms (seq=5273 running=16ms h=android.os.Handler c=com.sp1.fling.All_Fragments.Profile_F$2)
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: 1968ms before dispatchInputEvent (MotionEvent: event_seq=1999, seq=2399195, action=ACTION_DOWN)
D/numTouch: 91
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: 1806ms before dispatchInputEvent (MotionEvent: event_seq=2006, seq=2399233, action=ACTION_UP)
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: MotionEvent is 1681ms late (event_seq=2010, action=ACTION_DOWN) because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 2017ms (seq=5273 running=16ms h=android.os.Handler c=com.sp1.fling.All_Fragments.Profile_F$2)
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: 1681ms before dispatchInputEvent (MotionEvent: event_seq=2010, seq=2399237, action=ACTION_DOWN)
D/numTouch: 92
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: 1533ms before dispatchInputEvent (MotionEvent: event_seq=2017, seq=2399269, action=ACTION_UP)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: MotionEvent is 1368ms late (event_seq=2021, action=ACTION_DOWN) because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 2017ms (seq=5273 running=16ms h=android.os.Handler c=com.sp1.fling.All_Fragments.Profile_F$2)
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: 1368ms before dispatchInputEvent (MotionEvent: event_seq=2021, seq=2399273, action=ACTION_DOWN)
D/numTouch: 93
W/Looper: Slow Looper main: doFrame is 2036ms late because of 1 msg, msg 1 took 2017ms (seq=5273 running=16ms h=android.os.Handler c=com.sp1.fling.All_Fragments.Profile_F$2)
W/InputEventReceiver: App Input: 1214ms before dispatchInputEvent (MotionEvent: event_seq=2034, seq=2399313, action=ACTION_UP)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2059ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=147673798631902, Vsync=147675831965276, OldestInputEvent=147674467743000, NewestInputEvent=147674587149000, HandleInputStart=147675835923456, AnimationStart=147675838424863, PerformTraversalsStart=147675838488821, DrawStart=147675845168196, SyncQueued=147675846321217, SyncStart=147675846668144, IssueDrawCommandsStart=147675847019654, SwapBuffers=147675857965956, FrameCompleted=147675858530383, DequeueBufferDuration=196000, QueueBufferDuration=283000, 
D/fling_: {"code":"200","msg":[{"response":"success"}]}
D/Main: Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:147675892
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 29321
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@aa951f1
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 267761869
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=29321, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5671580944013741474}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
W/com.sp1.fling: Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->currentActivityThread()Landroid/app/ActivityThread; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->mActivities:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord;->paused:Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService() returned 0x707c633940
    HIDL successfully loaded.
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-5671580944013741474, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AudienceNetworkActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5671580944013741473}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Activity resumed, time: 267762028
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.verbose"
W/com.sp1.fling: type=1400 audit(0.0:458671): avc: denied { read } for comm=46414E3A4153594E43202334 name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=21096 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c158,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/Main: Interstitial ad displayed.
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: check your code, if you are calling finish() before start another activity. call finish after start another activity.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel, checking with your solution, let's see

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel, no its not working, issue still persists